# sort items in an array based on a number of conditions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of correct scores that looks like this:

```
var correctScores = [
   {score: "2-2", code: "draw"},
   {score: "2-1", code: "home"},
   {score: "0-1", code: "away"},
   {score: "1-0", code: "home"},
   {score: "3-0", code: "home"},
   {score: "any home win", code: "home"},
   {score: "1-2", code: "away"},
   {score: "0-3", code: "away"},
   {score: "any draw", code: "draw"},
   {score: "0-0", code: "draw"},
   {score: "any away win", code: "away"},
   {score: "0-2", code: "away"},
   {score: "1-1", code: "draw"},
   {score: "2-0", code: "home"}
]
```

I have managed to sort them by `home`, `draw`, `away`, but am trying to extend this to the score also, so that they are in a consistent order. When I say consistent order I want the scores to be ordered so that the least number of goals are first in the array. Following that if there is the same number of goals, the game with more home goals should be shown first.

Currently my code looks like this and only sorts by `home`,`draw`, `away`. I am finding it difficult to extend this sorting method to also sort by score. The scores will also keep updating so these will not neccessarily always be the same scores that are in the array.

```
let order = { HOME: 1, DRAW: 2, AWAY: 3 };

correctScores.sort(function (a, b) { return order[a.code] - order[b.code]; });
```

I am attempting to get the array to look like this:

```
var correctScores = [
   {score: "1-0", code: "home"},
   {score: "2-0", code: "home"},
   {score: "3-0", code: "home"},
   {score: "2-1", code: "home"},
   {score: "any home win", code: "home"}

   {score: "0-0", code: "draw"},
   {score: "1-1", code: "draw"},
   {score: "2-2", code: "draw"},
   {score: "any draw", code: "draw"},

   {score: "0-1", code: "away"},
   {score: "0-2", code: "away"},
   {score: "0-3", code: "away"},
   {score: "1-2", code: "away"},
   {score: "any away win", code: "away"}

]
```

Can anyone give me any advice as to how I could extend this sorting method?

Comment: Hint: check if the result of your comparison is 0. If non-0, return the result. If 0 (both are equal according to this comparison), continue with another comparison, and so on. In simple cases you can use `||` to combine comparisons (`||` will stop evaluating on the first truthy expression), otherwise you'll need to use `if`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you need small keys for the order object and you need to split scores for sorting with the value.

Then you can chain the deltas beginning from index 1 and the sort by the delta of index zero.

```js
var correctScores = [{ score: "2-2", code: "draw" }, { score: "2-1", code: "home" }, { score: "0-1", code: "away" }, { score: "1-0", code: "home" }, { score: "3-0", code: "home" }, { score: "1-2", code: "away" }, { score: "0-3", code: "away" }, { score: "0-0", code: "draw" }, { score: "0-2", code: "away" }, { score: "1-1", code: "draw" }, { score: "2-0", code: "home" }],
    order = { home: 1, draw: 2, away: 3 };

correctScores.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getParts(s) { return s.split('-'); }
    var aa = getParts(a.score),
        bb = getParts(b.score);

    return order[a.code] - order[b.code] || aa[1] - bb[1] || aa[0] - bb[0];
});

console.log(correctScores);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Solution for updated question with a check if score is not splittable, then take an array with `Infinite` as value, because it will be sorted to bottom.

```js
var correctScores = [{ score: "2-2", code: "draw" }, { score: "2-1", code: "home" }, { score: "0-1", code: "away" }, { score: "1-0", code: "home" }, { score: "3-0", code: "home" }, { score: "any home win", code: "home" }, { score: "1-2", code: "away" }, { score: "0-3", code: "away" }, { score: "any draw", code: "draw" }, { score: "0-0", code: "draw" }, { score: "Any away win", code: "away" }, { score: "0-2", code: "away" }, { score: "1-1", code: "draw" }, { score: "2-0", code: "home" }],
    order = { home: 1, draw: 2, away: 3 };

correctScores.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getParts(s) {
        var t = s.split('-');
        return t.length === 1 ? [Infinity, Infinity] : t;
    }
    var aa = getParts(a.score),
        bb = getParts(b.score);

    return order[a.code] - order[b.code] || aa[1] - bb[1] || aa[0] - bb[0];
});

console.log(correctScores);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: there is one more catch I forgot to mention. There is also a `any away win`, `any away win`, `any draw` options. I have updated the question

Comment: that looks a bit mopre complicated. does it alway have on code `'draw'` with score `'any ...'`?

Comment: no apologies, the codes still correspond. I have updated the question! sorry again

Comment: Dios mio! You are superhuman! ***S***! Thank you very much for the help

Comment: just because this is such a good answer, would you mind explaining what the [Infinity, Infinity] is doing? Also, I would have thought it should be checking if `t.length === 3 ` as there are three words in `any home win`. This line bambozles me a bit `return t.length === 3 ? [Infinity, Infinity] : t;`

Comment: the result of splitting a string with `-` and you have no minus in it, you get an array with a single element. that is what i check. the array with `Infinity` is just the replacement if no splitted/numerical values are available.

Answer (score 0):

That way

```js
var correctScores = [
   {score: "2-1", code: "home"},
   {score: "1-0", code: "home"},
   {score: "3-0", code: "home"},
   {score: "2-0", code: "home"},

   {score: "1-1", code: "draw"},
   {score: "0-0", code: "draw"},
   {score: "2-2", code: "draw"},

   {score: "0-3", code: "away"},
   {score: "0-2", code: "away"},
   {score: "0-1", code: "away"},
   {score: "1-2", code: "away"}

];

var groups = {};
var scores = [];

correctScores.map(function(e) { 
  groups[e.code] = groups[e.code] || [];
  groups[e.code].push(e);
});

for(var i in groups) {
  groups[i].sort(function (a, b) {
    var scoreA = a.score.split('-').map(Number);
    var scoreB = b.score.split('-').map(Number);
    
    return scoreA[0]+scoreA[1] > scoreB[0]+scoreB[1] ? 1:(
     scoreA[0]+scoreA[1] < scoreB[0]+scoreB[1] ? -1:0);
  });
  scores = scores.concat(groups[i]);
}

console.log(scores);
```

Answer (score 0):

Including the new requirement:

```
  var correctScores = [
  {score: "2-2", code: "draw"},
  {score: "2-1", code: "home"},
  {score: "0-1", code: "away"},
  {score: "1-0", code: "home"},
  {score: "3-0", code: "home"},
  {score: "Any home win", code: "home"},
  {score: "1-2", code: "away"},
  {score: "0-3", code: "away"},
  {score: "any draw", code: "draw"},
  {score: "0-0", code: "draw"},
  {score: "Any away win", code: "away"},
  {score: "0-2", code: "away"},
  {score: "1-1", code: "draw"},
  {score: "2-0", code: "home"}
];

let order = { home: 1, draw: 2, away: 3 };

correctScores.sort(function (a, b) {
  s1 = parseInt(a.score.split("-")[0]);
  s2 = parseInt(b.score.split("-")[0]);
  s1s = s1+parseInt(a.score.split("-")[1]);
  s2s = s2+parseInt(b.score.split("-")[1]);
  if(a.score.toLowerCase().indexOf("any")>-1){s1=999;s1s=999;}
  if(b.score.toLowerCase().indexOf("any")>-1){s2=999;s2s=999;}
  if(order[a.code]<order[b.code]) return -1;
  if(order[a.code]>order[b.code]) return 1;
  if(s1s<s2s) return -1;
  if(s1s>s2s) return 1;
  if(s1>s2) return -1;
  if(s1<s2) return 1;  
});

console.log(correctScores);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ct6knnqb/1/